# Is there a way to insert value into an EMPTY List at a specific index

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Is there a way to insert value into an EMPTY List at a specific index in dart ??

or Like defining list of fixed length and inserting value at any specific index???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: Dart 2.7 comes with [Null Safety](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41611) (Thanks to @lrn for info) which won't allow to use the default constructor to prevent values as `null`.

Use [filled](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/List/List.filled.html) the fixed/growable list as:

```
// fixed size list
var fixedList = List<int>.filled(3, 0);
fixedList[2] = 100;
print(fixedList);

// mutable list

var growableList = [];
growableList.length = 3;
growableList[3] = 100;

// or

var growableList = List<int>.filled(3, 0, growable:true);
growableList.length = 13;
print(growableList);
```

Alternately you can declare a growing list with predefined values

```
var growingList = [0,0,0,0,0];
growingList[3] = 100;
```

and it will be safe to only set the values for the predefined values/indexes though this list will be able to add more values than five.

---

Removed in Dart 2.7+

You can define a list with size

```
// removed in dart 2.7 SDK, use filled or alternate solution
var myList = new List(5);
```

then use the index to set value as:

```
myList[3] = 100;
```

Comment: The `List([int length])` constructor will be removed in the Null Safety version of Dart (because it's not null safe).. You will still be able to use `List<int?>.filled(5, null)` to create a list pre-filled with nulls.

Comment: @lrn Yeah, thanks, just tested that, let me update the solution.